# change color of Formula field inside details section in Cystal Reports using vb.net at run time

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

i change color of text object by using this code

```
Dim dname1 As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject = CrystalReport21.Section2.ReportObjects("dname1")
dname1.Color = My.Settings.crdcolor  


'// is use this method 
'//but it not have color properties 
Dim  tField As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormulaFieldDefinition = CrystalReport21.DataDefinition.FormulaFields.Item("tField")
```

now i need to change color of field inside details section

Comment: you can do it in Crystal formula.